# React Popover component - Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make a color palette which functions like: when I hover over the `PaletteIcon` it should popover the color palette and I should be able to select the colors as desired. But after hovering when I try to select the color, the palette disappears. Is there any property which I can add to paper React component or some other way to achieve this? I checked the [Paper API documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/paper/#paper-api) but didn't find any solution.

Here is the link for [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-95qnu?file=/demo.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** remove `pointerEvents: "none"` to listening to events from the popover content, remove your anchor's (Fab) `onMouseLeave` and control the popover when hovering (`onMouseEnter`, `onMouseLeave`) its content or the popover's backdrop.

**NL;PR:** I modified your Pastebin to reflect that [change](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-demo-using-hover-events-y9bs5). Alternatively, you can opt for using a [state management API](https://next.material-ui.com/components/popover/#popupstate-helper)).

Comment: After the changes no doubt its working. I opted for [material-ui-popup-state](https://github.com/jcoreio/material-ui-popup-state) package and its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

`Popover` is not rendered in the same tree as your Button, it is not a descendant of Button so therefore this logic would be very hard to implement out-of-the-box.

You could remove `onMouseLeave` event and close the Popover once the color is selected. Or you could just control the popover with clicking on the Button.

Or you could add your custom Popover as a child of Button element and therefore hover will remain on parent.